# tomcat catalina.out file make again I already remove file using 'rm'

Tags: tomcat

I already remove catalina.out file using '**rm**'.

After then restart tomcat but it doesn't make the file again .

So, i make using '**vi**' and restart tomcat .

But it doesn't write on new file ..

I don't know how to make catalina.out file again .

I tried this.
I search on google but they told me using dev/null.But i already remove it.
It was too late using dev/null

---

i restart tomcat using startup.sh  and shutdown.sh

my server is AIX

Comment: Did you run shutdown.sh first and startup.sh after it?

Comment: How are you starting Tomcat?

Comment: I use'd that shell. I didin't solved this issue. So i installed tomcat again. lol